# Mailsystem Failure Delivery - Custom subject

Tags: apache, email, smtp

When a mail is bounced it has a standard subject.
Is it possible to change with a custom subject or the subject which we gave or with a dynamic subject?
I am building a simple system in php to count all send and not sent mails with the help of bounced mails.
So i need to parse the body of the bounced mail to find the email address to which the mail was not sent.
If there could be any other less overhead option then that could be nice. We can reduce the processing time to parse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send a custom x-mail-id header or use the standard Mail-ID header. You store in a table a map of the id to email addresses.

From there it is simple to find out which email bounced by matching the id to the email address in your table.

Comment: I am still working on it. if you would like to give a single line of example then it could save more time.

Answer (score 0):

That subject could be generated by any server along the path your mail message takes, so I'd say no, you can't change that.